# PythonMagick - why the parameters do not reflect the ones of 'convert'

Tags: python, imagemagick, pythonmagick

I'm doing

```
img = PythonMagick.Image('image.jpg')
img.threshold(30)
```

Why this does not correspond to manually running

```
convert -threshold 30%
```

Same for 0.3. Similar problem with `blur 0x1`

EDIT:
From documentation, threshold is related to quantum depth, which is usually 65536... So 30% is 19660.8 and the thread is solved?

Comment: Which documentation are you following?

Comment: I did not find any, so I was doing tests (and .__doc__) I found something here http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html but it does not describe how it works, definitely not like convert... I'd like to specify a percentage

Comment: What is `img`? Show us the code. Here is some documentation http://www.imagemagick.org/download/python/README.txt

Comment: From the edit part, did it work?

Comment: Thanks for the documentation, yes it did work for threshold (I hope ;) ) but it is not full, e.g. no monochrome()...